# On Rails ActiveRecord show count based on parameter

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have some reporting methods throughout my app and in some cases I want to return the count (for a dashboard), and in others, return the full result set for viewing the details of a report.

What I'm wondering, is there a way to dynamically choose to show the count (instead of what I'm doing here):

```
def get_query_results(reporting_parameters, count_only = true)
    #put together reporting details...
    if count_only
      MyModel.where(query).count
   else
      MyModel.where(query)
    end
end
```

I considered setting a local variable to the result of my query parameter, and then call count, but that queries the database again (and even if it didn't it could increase memory usage).

**Is there a way to do an effective way to do this in one query?** This is one of several queries I have like this in my app, otherwise I wouldn't care. Also, I'd use a ternary, but the actual query conditions in my app are much longer than my example here and it makes it unreadable.

Comment: Why don't you use @collection.count afterwards ?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you are doing this:

```
@collection = get_query_results(...)
```

Then you can do this afterwards instead of inside of the action:

```
@collection.count
```

And if you like to call another method:

```
def total_number(collection)
  collection.count
end

@collection = get_query_results(...)
no_of_records = total_number(@collection)
```

Comment: Unfortunately (and I mentioned this in the question) when I do that it makes two trips to the database. The queries are much more complex than my simple example and therefore I'm worried about performance.

Comment: I have updated my answer, and it will not query twice, it will return the count of the collection, simply, no database query.

Comment: I think you are trying to use caching ?

Comment: Unfortunately when I call `total_number` and pass in my query results it is still making a return trip to the database for a count. I'm in development with these reports, but I do cache on production instance.

Comment: Also, I didn't note in the original question, but these are class methods and not instance methods - so maybe that is my problem with it not caching results? For example I have a model called `VideoView` has a `self.get_video_views(params)` method and another model called `PageView` with it's own method, etc. I've kept them on the models because they could be used for other purposes than this report. Maybe I should move.

Comment: Nope, models are for those purpose, don't move them.

Comment: For the purposes of testing to see if it mattered if it re-queried the results, moving them didn't make a difference. Logically they belong in the model.